# Grep for a value greater than integer in random place in a line

Tags: awk, grep

Grep for a value greater than a known value in a random place in a string.

For example,
My file is

```
a:10,c:10/2,b:999/3,d:9999/3
a:10,b:1000/2,c:999/3,d:9999/3
```

Here the value of b is the value after division. b=1000/2 is 500

Operation will be always division.

how do I grep for all the values of b>=500. Given that b can appear any where in the line?

Comment: Not clear. b:999/3 means that b=333 or b=999 ?

Comment: It is actual division 333

Comment: Is it always a division or sometimes you can have other operators ?

Comment: Just always division

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Should line one be included? `b=999`, then `999/3=333`, so its less than `500`.  You have accepted an answer that divided by `2` for all lines???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!  There is no `eval` function but given that it's always a division, you can just implement it.

```
$ awk -F'[,:]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) 
                   if($i=="b") 
                     {split($(i+1),b,"/"); 
                      if(b[1]/b[2]>=100) print $i":"$(i+1)}}' file

b:999/3
b:1000/2
```

you can also print the computed value, but not clear what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(tested with GNU `awk`), considering that your Input_file will be same as shown samples.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[:/]";RS="[\n,]"} $1=="b" && ($2/$3>=500)'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS=, -F'[:/]' '$1=="b" && ($2/$3)>=500' file
b:1000/2
```